# Select random records until a cumulative total is exceeded

Tags: query, sqlite, sqlite3

I have a table of videos with an `id`, `skill_level` and `duration` column and I am attempting to write a query that will return a playlist of distinct videos that has a total duration exceeding `X`.

```
select _id, duration, running_total
from (select *, sum(duration) over (order by RANDOM()) as running_total
      from videos
      where skill_level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner') AND watched IS NULL
     )
where running_total <= 7200;
```

This works and returns the following:

```
5e4d11fbaac87f3820954c45|305|305
64e51ad279223a9ad03525c2|930|1235
5e4d1204aac87f3820954c64|627|1862
5e4d1212aac87f3820954c95|367|2229
641e05c2d7c1512d278dc51a|361|2590
5e4d1200aac87f3820954c57|444|3034
649aa7089776ba12d8de28d5|329|3363
5e4d123eaac87f3820954d2c|573|3936
5e4d1216aac87f3820954ca1|399|4335
5e4d120daac87f3820954c84|315|4650
5e4d11dfaac87f3820954be1|510|5160
64f7036d3d578af923ba2afc|326|5486
5e4d11fcaac87f3820954c47|437|5923
5fa51afc27a912152cc51c33|1062|6985
```

But ideally I want to return enough records to exceed `X` but only by one. `6375274c1cff4a7e31b04a0d` below puts us over `7200`.

```
5e4d11fbaac87f3820954c45|305|305
64e51ad279223a9ad03525c2|930|1235
5e4d1204aac87f3820954c64|627|1862
5e4d1212aac87f3820954c95|367|2229
641e05c2d7c1512d278dc51a|361|2590
5e4d1200aac87f3820954c57|444|3034
649aa7089776ba12d8de28d5|329|3363
5e4d123eaac87f3820954d2c|573|3936
5e4d1216aac87f3820954ca1|399|4335
5e4d120daac87f3820954c84|315|4650
5e4d11dfaac87f3820954be1|510|5160
64f7036d3d578af923ba2afc|326|5486
5e4d11fcaac87f3820954c47|437|5923
5fa51afc27a912152cc51c33|1062|6985
6375274c1cff4a7e31b04a0d|1138|8123
```

Is it possible to write a query to achieve this in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, the task is to get a list of records with a sum less then threshold, and one additional record to go over the threshold?

This can be achieved by using `with` and `union` clauses:

```
with
below_threshold as materalized (
  select _id, duration, running_total
  from (select *, sum(duration) over (order by RANDOM()) as running_total
        from videos
        where skill_level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner') AND watched IS NULL
       )
  where running_total <= 7200
),
one_more as (
  select _id, duration
  from videos
  where skill_level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner') AND watched IS NULL
        and _id not in (select _id from below_threshold)
  limit 1
  order by random()
)
select _id, duration from below_threshold
union
select _id, duration from one_more
```

or you can do a pre-selection:

```
with
to_consider as (
  select _id, duration
  from videos
  where skill_level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner') AND watched IS NULL
),
below_threshold as materalized (
  select _id, duration, running_total
  from (select *, sum(duration) over (order by RANDOM()) as running_total
        from to_consider
       )
  where running_total <= 7200
),
one_more as (
  select _id, duration, (select sum(duration) from below_threshold)+duration as running_total
  from to_consider
  where _id not in (select _id from below_threshold)
  limit 1
  order by random()
)
select _id, duration, running_total from below_threshold
union
select _id, duration, running_total from one_more
```

EDIT:
Please note, this answer uses an `SQLite` only feature of materialized CTE. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#materialization_hints
This addition is necessary for CTE which uses `random()` for sorting and therefore provides a non-determenistic result.

Comment: So it turns out that a CTE is evaluated every time it is referenced. I only noticed after seeing duplicate results for some queries. It looks like the best way to do this is to use a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I thought White Owl's answer was good but after a few queries I noticed some issues:

1. When I attempted to bring the running total over from `below_threshold` to include in `one_more`  I noticed that the max value didn't match up with the records returned in `below_threshold`.
2. On more than one occasion I noticed duplicate records returned in the playlist set.

It turns out that CTEs are evaluated each time they are referenced, that combined with the `order by random()` leads to a non-deterministic CTE which is different each time it is [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891685/196834).

Inspired by White Owl's answer I have developed a solution using a temp table which makes allows us to "cache" the results of the first query:

```
CREATE temp TABLE runtime AS
    select *, sum(duration) over (order by RANDOM()) as running_total
                from videos
                where level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner') AND watched is null;

with below_threshold as (
    select _id, youtube_id, duration, running_total
    from runtime
    where running_total < 7200
    order by running_total
),
one_more as (
    select _id, youtube_id, duration, duration + (select running_total from below_threshold order by running_total desc limit 1)
    from videos
    where level in ('beginner', 'superbeginner')
        and watched is null
        and youtube_id not in (select youtube_id from below_threshold)
        and duration > 7200 - (select running_total from below_threshold order by running_total desc limit 1)
    order by duration asc
    limit 1
)
select * from below_threshold
union
select * from one_more
order by 4;
drop table runtime;
```

White Owl feel free to edit your answer and I will re-reward the correct answer to you.

Comment: You do not need a separate temp table. The pre-selection can be done inside the same `with` clause as first table (as I showed already in the second example).

Comment: There are three references to `below_threshold`. Two in `one_more` and another in the union. So the results will be different due to the `order by random()` no?

Comment: Kind of yes and no. Sorry, forgot to mention it initially, but since we are using sqlite, we can use it's feature - "materialized cte". That is essentially a temp table resolved at the moment of definition. The "not materialized cte" would be a "hidden" sub-select in the the main query and would be subjected to non-deterministic result. The SQL Server always does it, but sqlite is smarter in that regard :) Adding this comment to my first answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I appreciate it.